# Ripped paper icon instead of image on web page

Tags: php, image, apache2, localhost

I have some problem in displaying images after reading them from a folder in php. Im displaying them using echo "...." to display. The problem is that I can see their names on my page e.g. 1.jpg etc... but instead of images a ripped page icon is being shown. I'm working in linux so Ive granted all rights to all users. Ive read this normally occurs when images are not uploaded which doesn't apply to my situation.

```
$folder = '/var/www/pics/'."$usern".'/';
$filetype = '*.*';
$files = glob($folder.$filetype);
echo '<table>';
for( $i=0; $i<count($files); $i++)
{
echo '<tr><td>';
echo '<a name="'.$i.'" href="#'.$i.'"><img src="'.$files[$i].'"/></a>';
echo  substr($files[$i],strlen($folder),strpos($files[$i], '.')-strlen($folder));
echo '</td></tr>';
}
echo '</table>';
```

Note: $usern is the name of the folder whose images are being accessed.

Comment: Thank you for adding the code. I'm not sure, but you might need to check that the path is correct; I think you're currently outputting just the filename - maybe if you tried `img src="/pics/' . $usern' . '/'.$files[$i].'"`, or somesuch?

Comment: What I can see so far is an icon and image name

Comment: Have a look at the HTML you're generating, and check the `img src` that your code is outputting. Is it just the filename? Or does it have the path in there, too?

Comment: Ive given path name in $folder. Plus $folder and $filetype are both being used in $files.

Comment: I don't know what you mean, I'm sorry. `$files[$i]` is either going to be just the filename (which won't work, because there's no directory), or the full pathname on the system, eg `/var/www/pics/'."$usern".'/filename.jpg`, which won't work, because the webserver doesn't have  a `/var/www/` folder.

Comment: Don't be. Ive told you I have given path name in variable named $folder. Sorry i forgot to tell you that I am working on local server :P So in linux its path is like that.

Comment: It doesn't matter what server you're using. You're still using the wrong path in the `src`.

Comment: I got your point. Working on it...

Answer (score 0):

You're refering your images to a server folder. Which is server-side (duh). You need to point it towards your relative webpage path.

For example: Folder needs to be:

```
$folder = "http://www.yourdomain.com/pics/$usern/";
```

Comment: Well, I am both server and client. Its not working this way :(